# Removing object element from HashSet

Tags: java, object, hashset

I am working on a Wallet and have started with the basics. I am adding Penny objects into a HashSet which stores the money. I initialise the capacity to 5 and start with a full wallet.

When trying to spend a Penny, null is returned (as expected) but then when calling the moneyCheck() method, there are still 5 coins.

I am not sure what to do as I am trying to remove a Penny using the .remove() method and the object is not being removed from the HashSet.

```java
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Wallet{
    private HashSet<Penny> walletPenny;

    public Wallet(){
        int walletCapacity = 5;
        walletPenny = new HashSet<>();

        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < pocketCapacity){
            pocketPenny.add(new Penny());
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public Penny removePenny(){
        Penny spentPenny = null;

        if (walletPenny.isEmpty()){
            System.out.print("No more pennies!\n");
            return spentPenny;
        }
        else {
            pocketPenny.remove(spentPenny);
            System.out.println(("Spent penny!"));
        }
        return spentPenny;
    }

    public int moneyCheck(){
        System.out.print("Money remaining: " + walletPenny.size() + "\n");
        return walletPenny.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `removePenny()`method, spentPenny is never initialised, it's always null.
In fact your code will not compile.

Comment: Note that your model isn't really sound. On the one hand, you are using a SET, to collect penny objects, on the other hand, you KNOW that the money corresponds to the number of ENTRIES in that set. There really isnt much point of doing that. In your case, your "wallet" could just hold an int counter value! Pennies are all the same, or do you distinguish the penny coins in your real wallet? Nope, you only care about the overall number of them.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer and thought I will update this in case anyone else has the same issue.

To remove the penny I initialised a Penny object with an iterator to find the next available object in the HashSet.
I then returned that value to be used elsewhere in the program.

```
    public Penny removePenny(){
        Penny spentPenny;

        if (walletPenny.isEmpty()){
            System.out.print("No more pennies!\n");
            spentPenny = null;
            return spentPenny;
        }
        else {
            spentPenny = walletPenny.iterator().next();
            walletPenny.remove(spentPenny);
            System.out.println(("Spent penny!"));
            return spentPenny;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This misses the real point of your problem: the missing equals/hashCode methods on your Penny class.

Answer (score 0):

When you *try* to remove the penny with `pocketPenny.remove(spentPenny)`, Java tries to find *which* penny to remove. In order to do that, it uses `equals` and iterates the `HashSet` until it finds a penny which is equal (identity wise) to your `spentPenny`. [More on how `remove()` works](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)). Since you provide null as `spentPenny`, it will match nothing (your 5 pennies are initialized, so they are not null). You can verify this if you check the return value of `.remove()` method - it will be `false`.

In order to fix this, you need to:

1. Provide a non-null value when you call the `remove()` method
2. Implenent `equals()` in your `Penny` class
3. Keep track of which Pennies you created so you can remove them later

Full example:

```java
public class Penny {

    private final int serialNum;

    public Penny(int serialNum) {
        this.serialNum = serialNum;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 79 * hash + this.serialNum;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Penny other = (Penny) obj;
        return this.serialNum == other.serialNum;
    }

}
```

and then create your Pennies:

```java
int counter = 0;
        while (counter < pocketCapacity){
            pocketPenny.add(new Penny(counter));
            counter++;
        }
```

Now you have 5 pennies, numbered 0 to 4. You can remove one, for example #3:

```java
Penny spentPenny = new Penny(3);
pocketPenny.remove(spentPenny);
```